# testcomplete dealing with save file in wordpad

Tags: automated-tests, testcomplete

could anyone help how to deal with ribbon commnad bars in testcomplete
I'm trying to save a wordpad file 
I'm writing the next code

```
function saveFile() {
TestedApps.wordpad.Run();
var pWordPad = Sys.Process("wordpad");
var wWordPad = pWordPad.Window("WordPadClass", "Документ - WordPad", 1).Window("RICHEDIT50W", "",     1);
wWordPad.Keys("smth");

var ribbon = pWordPad.Window("WordPadClass", "* - WordPad",  1).Window("UIRibbonCommandBarDock", "UIRibbonDockTop", 3).Window("UIRibbonCommandBar", "Ribbon",   1).Window("UIRibbonWorkPane", "Ribbon", 1).Window("NUIPane", "", 1).Window("NetUIHWND", "", 1);
```

}
Here I'm stack...I wonder how to open dialog save file?
I tried like this

```
ribbon.Click("File|Save as...");
```

however, it doen't work

Comment: Did you try recording the actions?

Comment: yes, I tried, but It recordet the coordinates of the button Save as. i'm interesting why the method mainmenu.clik("File|Save as..,") doesn't work as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use keyboard shortcuts to work with Ribbon in WordPad.

```
function wordPadSaveAs()
{
  var wordpad = Sys.Process("wordpad");
  wndWordPadClass = wordpad.Window("WordPadClass", "*");
  wndWordPadClass.Activate();
  Sys.Keys("~fa");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the **NetUIHWND** class name to the *MSAA* or *UI Automation* list so that TestComplete could recognize different objects on a ribbon. After this, try recording the actions.

[image]